# How to make 'onUp' event if my inputs have two states 0 & 1?

Tags: javascript, dom-events

Here is my trouble.

- When the button is off it hase value 0.
- When it is pressed it turns to 1.
- When it is released it gets back to 0.

Now I was using the following code to listen to change event:

```
if (obj[0].state.A === 1) {
    //do some thing
}
```

The problem is I have the function that wraps around my code.
It is TICK function which resets `$obj.state.A` to 0 if it is not pressed.
It ticks every 0.10ms.

Now here is where the problem is, `$if (obj[0].state.A === 1)` gives my code that executes when the button is down.
But I need to make it happen on button up! event and only once in one press.

How do I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found it!

This is how I did it:

```
if (gamepads[0].state.A === 1 && this.lastStateA == 0) {
      //do stuff
}
this.lastStateA = gamepads[0].state.A;
```

Answer (score 0):

if I understood correctly, try this:

```
jQuery('#button').bind('mouseup', function(event){
    if (jQuery(this).state === 1) {
        doJob(); // here your code fires
    }
})
```

Comment: Jacky Qwerty tnx. But is not actualy it. I am not trying to manipulate some DOM buttons or anithing els. I have a spesial controller. Which i had hooked up to browser und now trying to configure it.